# Reading Hard Disk at Byte Level

Tags: python, windows, hard-drive, hexdump

Situation: I am writing a python program to read through a hard disk (specifically Windows) and compare hex strings with each other.

Problem: Is it possible to do so? The solution I am looking for needs to be fast, therefore `dd` is unsuitable.

I understand that on Linux systems we can do an `open('/dev/sdX', 'r')`. I found another question that suggests that I use `open('\\.\PhysicalDriveX', 'r')` or `open('\\.\C:', 'r')` on "Win32-based applications".

Question: Does the above command work on normal Windows machines (64-bit) as well?

Additional information: I am using ePython, a variation of Python, with additional functionalities.

Comment: `\\.\PhysicalDrive[N]` is a disk. `\\.\C:` is a volume (typically a single partition). Reading them directly requires administrator rights, and they should be opened in binary mode, i.e. `"rb"`.

Comment: Volumes can also be mounted in NTFS directories. Opening such a volume from the Windows API requires the volume GUID name, which you can get from either a drive letter or folder mountpoint via `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint`. This function requires a trailing backslash on the mountpoint path. It returns the GUID volume name with a trailing backslash, which you'll need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach would be to stick with the Linux method using the built in Linux subsystem on Windows with:

Windows 10:

Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Winows 7:

Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391

I've used the Windows 10 - Home Edition, Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows at it works like a charm.

Comment: But Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows is only on Windows 10. The systems I need to scan are on Windows 7 (Ancient, I know)

Comment: Sorry I am adding more requirements... Assume I have no administrative privileges to install anything on said computers. My job is just to plug my program in and it will run and scan the system - no more, no less. But I think you can leave your post as it is - it's may be very informative to others.

Comment: Have you considered creating a live install USB, loaded with Xubuntu (xcfe GUI) or Lubuntu (even lighter weight)?  It would give you a lot more flexibility than a guest account on Windows 7. This is assuming the entire drive(s) aren't encrypted.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea but the focus is speed and minimal interactions with the computer. Booting into a live environment will take sometime and I am not sure if I am able to write a script for that. (It is supposed to be a plug-n-scan thing.

Comment: A lot depends on the details of your task to 'read through a hard disk', the load time from a live usb image is faster than a Windows 7 boot in my experience. the boot time will likely to be trivial compared to byte reading a significant amount of data.

Comment: That is a point. I'll check if I am allowed to do that. In the meantime, thank you for your time